# SequenceGenerator problem with unit testing in Hsqldb/H2

Tags: java, hsqldb, h2

I have tried using both Hsqldb and H2 for unit testing but facing problem with sequence generators. Field declaration looks like this.

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="keyword_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="keyword_seq",sequenceName="KEYWORD_ID_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name="IM_KEYWORD_ID")
private Long keywordId;
```

When I try to test simple insert in this table in Hsqldb with following configuration, it gives error

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_ora=true</prop>
```

Error :

```
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: KEYWORD_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
```

With H2:

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/test</prop>
```

Error is :

```
Hibernate: select KEYWORD_ID_SEQ.nextval from dual
3085 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 42001, SQLState: 42001
3088 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT KEYWORD_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM[*] DUAL "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
```

Any idea, how to solve this?

Comment: All my classes are annotation based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the dialect is set wrongly. Can you check your hibernate configuration.

Comment: I am using follwing. `<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>`

Comment: You need to change it to org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect for HSQL and org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect for H2. As you notice hibernate is firing Oracle queries against HSQL & H2 database, hence the errors.

Comment: I changed to dialect, you mentioned but still getting error. For HSQLDB, error is `user lacks privilege or object not found: KEYWORD_ID_SEQ`. For H2, its `ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Sequence "KEYWORD_ID_SEQ" not found; SQL statement:call next value for KEYWORD_ID_SEQ [90036-147]`. Do we need to create some sequences at time of startup ourselves?

Comment: Yes, you need to use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create - so that the database schema is created during startup.

Comment: Thanks a lot gkamal, I am using annotated class so I guess `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is not required. Just changing Dialect made it work. It was some typo earlier or was feeling sleepy.

Comment: Great, I think you are already using hbm2ddl.auto, without that it wouldn't work. That is not just for hbm the same flag applies to annotations as well.  HSQL / H2 are in memory databases so schema needs to be dynamically setup every time.  Also can you please mark my answer as the correct answer.